# Why is the value for ${applicationName} not supplied after migrating my Flutter app to Android embedding v2?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, deprecated

I tried to immigrate a deprecated flutter application, but after following the steps provided on github im getting this

```
C:\Users\personal\AndroidStudioProjects\flash-chat-flutter\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:10:9-42 Error:
    Attribute application@name at AndroidManifest.xml:10:9-42 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <applicationName> is provided.
C:\Users\personal\AndroidStudioProjects\flash-chat-flutter\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    Validation failed, exiting
```

Comment: Can you add your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 18):

I ran into this as well. In my case it was because I had set `manifestPlaceholders` the "usual" way, by assigning with `=` (as all examples seem to do):

In `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
android {
    ⋮
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.my_app"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        // This right here!
        manifestPlaceholders = [someKey: "@string/some_value"]
    }
    ⋮
}
```

It turns out that [multidex support](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/90944) introduced the need to dynamically determine the application name, hence the `${applicationName}` placeholder in the manifest.

That value is determined by the Flutter Gradle plugin [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/935d1478aac8329016846131c4d0091ed011be87/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle#L254-L284) by means of `manifestPlaceholders`, so if you *replace* the value by reassigning it then you will run into this issue. The fix is simple: *add* your values to the existing ones with `+=` like so:

```
android {
    ⋮
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.my_app"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        // Fixed now! Note the plus!
        manifestPlaceholders += [someKey: "@string/some_value"]
    }
    ⋮
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error:

You need to add this to your build.gradle (YourFlutterProject/android/app/build.gradle)

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        manifestPlaceholders = [applicationName: "android.app.Application"]
    }

    debug {
        manifestPlaceholders = [applicationName: "android.app.Application"]
    }
    build{
        manifestPlaceholders = [applicationName: "android.app.Application"]
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not need to do this; the framework does it for you. In fact the framework *needs* to do it dynamically in order to handle multidex scenarios properly. Per my answer, you simply need to avoid *overwriting* the values the framework provides.